# Import ASP.net Visual Studio files into mono

Tags: mono

How to import ASP.net Visual Studio files into new mono project ?
i.e. add the entire tree structure to a new mono project ?

Comment: Which Mono development environment are you using ? If you're using Monodevelop, I'm pretty sure I just opened my .SLN file and imported it. but it's been a while.

Answer (score 2):

MonoDevelop supports loading Visual Studio .sln solution files, so there's no need to "import" anything.